# Meanwhile as a preposition

Tags: prepositions

I'm currently taking an English course that involves picking out adverbs, nouns, prepositions, and pronouns. Myself and my tutor are at a disagreement on if the use of meanwhile in this situation is a preposition. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

"These obedient servants prepare meals at the appropriate times, groom them and clean the sanitary facilities. Meanwhile, the servants who pay the taxes and buy the groceries wonder sometimes who is really in charge."

Comment: It should be "My tutor and I are in disagreement". Reflexive pronouns like _myself_ can't be used as subjects, even conjoined subjects.

Comment: How very prescriptivist of you. John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A preposition is (by definition) followed by a NP (noun phrase) and forms a bigger unit (a PP - preposition phrase) with it.

In your example, "meanwhile" happens to be followed by a NP, but does not form a unit with it, so it is not a preposition.

[There are some words, such as *after* which can be used both as prepositions and in different ways, but *meanwhile* is not one of them as far as I know].

Comment: ... In the example 'Popeye the sailorman', Popeye isn't a preposition either. Neither is it an adverb, though 'meanwhile' is. It modifies the words describing the activity / mental activity / state (here, ... wonder ...).

Comment: Isn't it effectively an ***adverbial*** usage in OP's context? Modifying the verb ***wonder***? In fact, isn't it *always* an adverb unless used as a noun *(in the meanwhile)?*.

Comment: I've seen it called a conjunctive adverb.

Comment: The [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meanwhile) give only adverbial uses of `meanwhile`.